# PESSIMISTIC_READ lock on same entity cannot be acquired by 2 services

Tags: jpa, ejb

From JPA documentation, PESSIMISTIC_READ lock on an entity can be acquired if no one is holding a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock on the entity. However, as I tested using OpenJPA 2.0.0, WebSphere and MSSQL (as well as DB2), it seems that 2 services cannot acquire PESSIMISTIC_READ lock on the same entity at the same time.

This code (in ConfigEJB) was used to lock the entity:

```
ConfigEntity configEntity = this.getEntityById(1); // successfully get the entity
this.entityManager.lock(configEntity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ);
```

2 instances of ConfigEJB were invoked. The first instance could acquire the lock successfully. However, the second instance couldn't get the lock, and was blocked until the first instance finished its transaction (I expected it to successfully get the lock).

Has anyone ever encountered this problem? Or is this an expected behavior of JPA? How to let the services obtain PESSIMISTIC_READ locks properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not found in reference, but Pro JPA2 saying:

Some databases support locking mechanisms to get repeatable read isolation without acquiring a write lock. A PESSIMISTIC_READ mode can be used to pessimistically achieve repeatable read semantics when no writes to the entity are expected. The fact that this kind of situation will not be encountered very often, combined with **the allowance that providers have of implementing it using a pessimistic write lock**, leads us to say that this mode is not one to be easily picked up and commonly used.

So, seems your database provider replace PESSIMISTIC_READ with PESSIMISTIC_WRITE

Comment: Thank you. After your answer, I tried searching for information about PESSIMISTIC_READ implementation and found this in OpenJPA 2.3 manual: "OpenJPA differentiates between PESSIMISTIC_READ and PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock modes only with DB2 databases. While running with other databases, there is no distinction between these two modes because PESSIMISTIC_READ lock mode is upgraded to PESSIMISTIC_WRITE". So it's because of OpenJPA implementation.